# Spring cloud stream dosent create automatically quorum queue

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, queue, spring-cloud-stream, quorum

I want to use quorum queue in our application but I found that spring doesn't create the queue automatically as he does with classique queue.

I didnt find such information about auto creation of quorum queue.

Can someone help me?

Regard

Answer (score 0):

See `quorum.enabled` and related properties

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/docs/3.2.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_rabbitmq_consumer_properties

> **quorum.enabled**

> When true, create a quorum queue instead of a classic queue.

> Default: false